# Javascript object property undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to build a reddit api wrapper for node.js.  I am fairly new to OO javascript and I am having an issue with assigning a value to my reddit object's properties.

```
var request = require("request");
var subreddit = require("./subreddit").subreddit;

var reddit = function () {

  var self = this,
      userAgent = "node.js api wrapper - https://github.com/theyshookhands/rednode",
      debug = false,
      cookie = "",
      uh = "";  

  self.getJSON = function (url, data, callback) {
    data["api_type"] = "json";
    request(url, { qs: data }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        callback(body);
      }
    });
  };

  self.post = function (url, data, callback) {
    console.log("in post");
    console.log("cookie: " + self.cookie);
    console.log("uh: " + self.uh);
    data["api_type"] = "json";
    if (self.cookie) {
      request.cookie(self.cookie);
      console.log("cookie assigned");
    }
    if (self.uh) {
      data["uh"] = self.uh;
      console.log("uh assigned");
    }
    console.log("requesting");
    request.post(url, { form: data }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log("no errors");
        callback(body);
      }
    });
  };

};

reddit.prototype = {

  login: function (username, password, callback) {
    var data = {
      "user": username,
      "passwd": password,
      "rem": false
    };

    this.post("http://www.reddit.com/api/login", data, function (body) {
      var response = JSON.parse(body);
      this.uh = response["json"]["data"]["modhash"];
      this.cookie = response.json.data.cookie;
      console.log("rednode --> logged in as: " + username);
      callback();
    });
  },

  setUserAgent: function (userAgent) {
    this.userAgent = userAgent;
  },

  r: function (name, callback) {
    var sr = new subreddit(name);
    if (callback) {
      sr.exec(callback);
    }
    return sr;
  },

  postLink: function (sr, title, url, callback) {
    var data = {
      "kind": "link",
      "sr": sr,
      "title": title,
      "url": url
    };
    console.log("calling post");
    this.post("http://www.reddit.com/api/submit", data, callback);
  }
}

exports.reddit = reddit;
```

The objects are defined at lines 15 and 16.  They are given values at lines 62 and 63.  Why am I not reaching these values using the

```
this.cookie, this.modhash
```

syntax?

Comment: Thanks, Lee.  I wasn't sure if it was more appropriate to link the the github page or post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function:

```
var reddit = function () {
```

Why use a function expression where a function declaration will do and is likely clearer? And by convention, constructors start with a capital letter:

```
function Reddit() {
```

In the function:

```
  var self = this,
```

The value of a function's `this` is determined entirely by how the function is called. Since this is a constructor, when called with `new` its `this` will reference a newly constructed object (an "instance" of the constructor).

```
  var self = this,
      userAgent = "...",
      debug = false,
      cookie = "",
```

The above creates **variables** on the local execution object's variable object. You can only access variables by name, they are resolved on the scope chain of execution objects, ending with the global object.

```
...
self.post = function (url, data, callback) {
    console.log("in post");
    console.log("cookie: " + self.cookie);
```

Here, `self` on the LHS references the Reddit instance. On the RHS, the function expression has a closure to the outer scope so its `self` also references the same instance so you are looking for a `cookie` property on the object and its `[[Prototype]]` chain.

But you declared `cookie` as a local variable of the constructor, so the identifier is being resolved along the wrong chain (i.e. you should be looking for a variable on the scope chain, not a property on the object/`[[Prototype]]` chain).

It just so happens that because of the closure, you can use:

```
    console.log("cookie: " + cookie);
```

to resolve `cookie` on the scope chain.

But it seems like you really want to access it as a property, so just make it a public property in the first place:

```
  var self = this,
      userAgent = "...",
      debug = false;

  this.cookie = "", // or self.cookie = '',
  ...
```

Now you can use `self.cookie`.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation. It helped a lot. I am not by my code atm so I can't try it but wouldn't I still have an issue accessing the `cookie` and `uh` properties from the login function? That is where I get lost in what `this` would refer to.

Comment: Actually it would be from the anonymous function in the login function.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the keyword `this` to reference properties you have defined on your "object" they have to be within the same scope of the function/object.

You are incorrectly using the `this` keyword to reference the function/object variable/property which will actually be called `reddit.cookie` inside the scope of an unnamed callback function.

You must declare cookie as `this.cookie ="";` for it to be accessible as `reddit.cookie` however.

Comment: Declaring them using this.cookie and this.uh makes sense.  However, accessing them using reddit.cookie and reddit.uh doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @theyshookhands That is assuming that you declared the variable `reddit` in the global scope and that it is not wrapped inside of other functions or objects.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't really have the concept of private instance variables in the way you're trying to use them.

Only public members (explicitly set by saying this.whatever = "") can be accessed that way.

Otherwise you can still access them like any other variable by dropping the self. In front of them.

Answer (score 0):

In your `reddit` constructor function, you define private variables like `userAgent`, `cookie`. To define public properties for your `reddit` object instances, you must proceed like this in your constructor function :

```
this.debug = false;
```

See [this Douglas Crockford article](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) for more informations.